# All list of values for HTML rel attribute

Tags: html, rel

I would like to know more on `rel` attribute used with `a` html elements.
Does anyone know some list of attributes useful for SEO and social?

```
<a title="" rel="friend met neighbor" href="#">This is a link</a>
```

I know it only inside `WordPress` and it's links manager, but nothing more.

Answer (score 10):

HTML5 defines some values for the `rel` attribute: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes

For the use in HTML5, all other link types need to be defined/listed on this page in the microformats wiki:
http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

Values for the rel attribute, and the elements for which each is relevant