# Semantic markup for images in e-commerce

Tags: schema.org, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I have seen that various retailers prefer the `og:image` from OGP,`twitter:image` from Twitter Cards over the `image` property from Schema.org (`Product`), and that preference shows up in various ways like having high resolution images for `og:image` property and very low resolution or no value for the Schema.org `image` property.

If I need images should I give preference to the `og:image` and `twitter:image` over the Schema.org `image`?

If so is it just the current trend to prefer `og:image` and `twitter:image` over Schema.org `image`, or does it make sense because  Schema.org is intended for search engines where as the OGP and Twitter Cards are meant to convert the pages into social objects?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

- [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) and [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) are *vocabularies* for use with various syntaxes.
- [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview) is a set of *metadata names* for use with HTML’s `meta` element.

Consumers (like search engines, browser add-ons, social networks, etc.) decide

- which vocabularies (Schema.org, Open Graph protocol, Dublin Core, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669)),
- which syntaxes (RDFa, Microdata, JSON-LD, Turtle, RDF/XML, etc.),
- which conventions (Microformats),
- which metadata names (`keywords`, `description`, `twitter:image`, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669)), and
- which link types (`nofollow`, `external`, `home`, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450872/1591669))

they want to support.

If you only care about specific consumers, look up what they support and use this. If you also care about consumers you might not know about, use more/several (of the popular) ways.

In your specific example, you can easily implement all three ways:

```html
<!-- this is plain HTML5, 
     using the registered metadata name "twitter:card" -->
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/image.png">

<!-- this is HTML5+RDFa, 
     using the properties "og:image" (from Open Graph protocol) and "schema:image" (from Schema.org), 
     as defined in <http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1>  -->
<link property="og:image schema:image" href="http://example.com/image.png">
```

(Side note: Twitter should have defined *link types* instead of *metadata names* for values that are URLs, as it’s [required by HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669). Because they didn’t, you have to use `meta` instead of `link`; otherwise you [could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669) have used the same `link` element for all three.)

Comment: Thanks Unor for the excellent insight, I also wanted to know or validate what I see as being the current trend by the retailers to have images in ogp or twitter and not in Schema.org,and use schema.org for price related markup only.

Comment: Also would you happen to know any Java based API that lets you read the meta data tags like twitter:image  from an HTML page,given the URL of the page?

Comment: @user1965449: No, I don’t know any. You could ask a question on the sister site [softwarerecs.se].